# Where should i check if a user is authenticated server or client?

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using react and express but im not doing server side rendering but im using some routes such as /login /register to received data from react.. I am using react router for navigation with `HashRouter` my question is i am confuse where to check weather a user is authenticated should i do it on react or server? i.e checking if session exists.. i am using cookie-session to store some information. If it's not possible then is this where jwt tokens and passport js comes in?

Here's my server route 
i want to redirect to some react route but i can't do that because server and react routes works differently.

```
server.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('users').findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    }, (err, succ) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(succ && succ.email == req.body.email && succ.password == req.body.password){
            req.session.id = succ._id;
            res.end()
        } else {
            res.json({
                message: 'Invalid email or password!'
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Login.js

```
onAuth = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target.email.value;
    const password = e.target.password.value;
    fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: JSON.stringify({email: email , password: password}),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            validate: {
                message: res.message
            }
        })
        return res;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here's my App.js right now i am checking for the cookie if its existing this works but the page needs to be refresh to take effect..

```
class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
        cookie: Cookies.get('session') || false
    }
    render(){
        const {cookie} = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
        <Header/>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <ProtectedRoute cookie={cookie} path="/home" component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
            );
    }
}

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, cookie, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => cookie 
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />} />
  )
}
```

I am using `HashRouter` my react routes will be prefix with /#/:path

Comment: Your question is not clear as well as post if you tried any code?

Comment: Code is not my problem, the concept is my problem.

Comment: You should check it at the server side, the client side is out of your control

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez i know but im not relying on server routes so i cannot validate if a user is authenticated when they're on  `/home` route since this is react router

Comment: @PrabaharanRajendran i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

When using JWT you check authentication at the client.

For example, in your root component you dispatch an auth action in ComponentWillMount

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(reAuthUser(() => this.props.history.push("/login")));
  }
```

The auth function is like this.

```
export const reAuthUser = redirect => async dispatch => {
  const userInfo = getUserInfo();
  if (userInfo && userInfo.exp >= Date.now() / 1000) {
    dispatch(authUser(userInfo));
  } else if (userInfo && userInfo.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
    redirect();
  }
};

export const getUserInfo = () => {
  const token = getToken();
  let payload;
  if (token) {
    payload = token.split(".")[1];
    payload = window.atob(payload);
    return JSON.parse(payload);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export const getToken = () => localStorage.getItem("jwt-token");
```

Here is my implementation of create-react-app & Passport.js / JWT in an express app. (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/auth) Ignore the native file.

Comment: storing JWTs in localstorage is bad practice